# What is False Dependency in CPU?

Tags: pipeline, cpu, cpu-architecture, intel, cpu-hazard

Can someone help me understand what "false dependency" means?

My professor just explained in this slide why we can't run command 3 before command 1, but why later he called it "False"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "false" because the later instruction doesn't actually need data from earlier instruction.  The only conflict is finding a place to put the result.  Like the slide says, "not a real data dependency"; only RAW hazards are true dependencies.

If the CPU invents a temporary location to put the result, until the architectural register is available, it *can* execute the later instruction independently.  **Having to wait for this register to be ready is something you can avoid, therefore it's not a true dependency, it's false.**

Register renaming avoids [WAR and WAW hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards) in general, except for special cases where the CPU treats an instruction as having an input from a register even though the result doesn't depend on any of the bits there.

Since you tagged this [intel] even though your slide isn't x86 asm, maybe you'd prefer x86 examples:

- [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction) - writing the same register with a write-only instruction like `movss` breaks the dependency on the previous value, since x86 CPUs that do OoO exec also do register renaming.  One way to keep multiple `vfmadd` instructions in flight in a vector dot product is to use multiple registers to hold sums.
- [Why does breaking the "output dependency" of LZCNT matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390165/why-does-breaking-the-output-dependency-of-lzcnt-matter) - `lzcnt eax, edx` *should* be write-only for EAX, but Intel Haswell and Broadwell have a *false output dependency*, scheduling it like `bsr eax, edx` which does read EAX in case EDX is zero.
- [Replacing a 32-bit loop counter with 64-bit introduces crazy performance deviations with _mm_popcnt_u64 on Intel CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078285/replacing-a-32-bit-loop-counter-with-64-bit-introduces-crazy-performance-deviati/25089720#25089720) Same problem but for `popcnt`, false (output) dependency on Sandybridge-family until Ice Lake.  Interestingly, it runs [on the same execution unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802692/how-is-popcnt-implemented-in-hardware/28803917#28803917) as `lzcnt` / `bsr` / `tzcnt` / `bsf`.
- [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) - writing a partial register on many microarchitectures counts as read-modify-write of the full register, e.g. `mov di, 123` is scheduled similarly to `add edi, 123`, unlike `mov` to a 32 or 64-bit register which both [overwrite the whole register to avoid false dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-x86-64-instructions-on-32-bit-registers-zero-the-upper-part-of-the-full-6) without doing messy partial-register renaming.
- [Deoptimizing a program for the pipeline in Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361145/deoptimizing-a-program-for-the-pipeline-in-intel-sandybridge-family-cpus) - WAW and WAR false dependencies don't stall on SnB-family, neither do independent writes to the same memory location.

Comment: can you kindly explain why WAR isn't false dependency? we can use same trick...

Comment: @David: A WAR hazard can be considered a type of false dependency if a CPU stalls for it, I think.

Comment: "only WAR hazards are true dependencies" I think you meant read-after-write (RAW) instead of WAR here https://www.ida.liu.se/~TDTS08/labs/vliw/dependencies.html

Comment: @exepe: Yes, thanks, fixed. That was either a brain-fart or a typo!  Or I was half asleep; apparently I didn't clue in even when the OP asked about it in the previous comments.